# How do I add link forwarding in Flask code

Tags: url, flask

I have created flask applicatiosn on my server which has link like this

http://54.23.11.22:5003/search

But what I want is, If user enters `http://54.23.11.22`, he should be redirected to `http://54.23.11.22:5003/search`

Or even if it's possible to run my code directly on

'54.23.11.22'

That is also fine.

Any suggestion how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your code to look something like:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return redirect(url_for('.search'), code=302)


@app.route('/search')
def search():
    return render_template('search.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5003))
    app.run(host='54.23.11.22', port=port)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply. Can you please add some explaination that how does this work? I mean what will happen at each mentioned route and in `main` function